# Changing HTML code with Javascript show/hide

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried a few different things, including a switch statement, appending using JQuery etc. and I can't get this to work with the button. What I am trying to do is change the words in P2 from:

```
Please push `<button id = "me" onclick = "toggle1('me');">this </button>` to show more information about me.
```

to:

```
Please push `<button id = "me" onclick = "toggle1('me');">this </button>` to hide more information about me.
```

I have to do the same thing with "courses" but I think if I could understand the first one, I could get how to do the second see/hide on my own. 
I am so confused now :/

I think it has something to do with span tags, but I honestly am in my first week of HTML and have not learned what are probably really simple procedures for things like this yet.  I would appreciate any and all the help I can get to  help me figure this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>About me</title>
   <style>
    body 
    {
       background-color:#ADD8E6;
    }

    #p3 
    {
       display:none;
    }
    #myImage 
    {
       width:280px;
       height:280px;
    }
    #schedule
    {
       width: 100%;
       display:none;

    }
    </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language = "javascript" >
   function changeImage() 
   {


      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

      if (image.src.match("hrgswitch"))
      {
         image.src = "hrg.jpg";
      }
      else 
      {
         image.src = "hrgswitch.jpg";

      }


   }

   function toggle1(obj) 
   {
      if(obj == "me") 
      {
         if(document.getElementById("p3").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("p3").style.display == "") 
         {

            document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "block";



         }

}
         else
         {
            document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "none";
         }


      }
      else if (obj == "courses")
      {
         if(document.getElementById("schedule").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("schedule").style.display == "")
         {
            document.getElementById("schedule").style.display = "block";
         }
         else
         {
            document.getElementById("schedule").style.display = "none";
         }

      }
    }


</script>

</head> 

<body>

<h1> My Page </h1>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage();" src="hrg.jpg" />

<p title="About Me">
Stuff about me <br>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Here is a link to learn more about HTML!</a>
<br>
<br>
</p>



<p id = "p2">
   <br>
   <br>
   Please push <button id = "me" onclick = "toggle1('me');">this </button> to see more information about me. 
   <br>
   <br>
   Please push <button id = "courses" onclick = "toggle1('courses');">this </button> to see my list of courses."
 </p>

 <p id = "p3" >


More stuff about me... 
<br>

</p>



<br>


<table id = "schedule">
  <tr>
    <td>Course Name</td>
    <td>Date</td>       
    <td>Time</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Programming Paradigms</td>
    <td>Tuesday / Thursday</td>     
    <td>11:00-12:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Computer Organization</td>
    <td>Tuesday / Thursday</td>     
    <td>9:30-10:45</td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Linear Algebra</td>
    <td>Monday/Wednesday/Friday</td>        
    <td>11:50-12:40</td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Combinatorics </td>
    <td>Monday/Wednesday/Friday</td>        
    <td>8:35-9:25</td>
  </tr>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using JQuery you can use methods like `.hide()` and `.show()`. By this same token `.toggle()` does both of those but flipping back and forth when called. Sooo `document.getElementById("p3").show()` instead of using `block`.

Comment: instead of changing the display property directly, you might consider setting up a css class that adds none. That way all you have to concern yourself with is adding or removing the class.

Comment: You can assign a class to P2 words by simply using a span and then you can use jQuery click function and html function to replace the text. http://api.jquery.com/click/ and http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath OP isn't using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Syntax Error in your function `toggle1`. Remove unwanted braces. Try this:

```
<script language = "javascript" >
   function toggle1(obj) 
   {
      if(obj == "me") 
      {
         if(document.getElementById("p3").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("p3").style.display == "") 
         {

            document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "block";



         }

         else
         {
            document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "none";
         }


      }
      else if (obj == "courses")
      {
         if(document.getElementById("schedule").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("schedule").style.display == "")
         {
            document.getElementById("schedule").style.display = "block";
         }
         else
         {
            document.getElementById("schedule").style.display = "none";
         }

      }
    }


</script>
```

**But, if you are using jQuery, `toggle` is an inbuilt function. this is very simple as(Inline JS - Although Recommended as seperate Script): Remove your `toggle1` function and change your two html onclick attributes:**

```
Please push <button id = "me" onclick = "$('#p3').toggle()">this </button> to see more information about me. 

Please push <button id = "courses" onclick = "$('#schedule').toggle()">this </button> to see my list of courses.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I plan to edit the braces in just a moment. As for jQuery and toggle, is there a way to change see to hide or hide to see without that, since that's now how my code is set up so far? I guess I'm just really not understanding how to do that. If all else fails and I do have to use jQuery for simplicity, how do you implement the part that would change see and hide on toggle? Sorry if I'm asking too much, I just really want to understand. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Heather, are you asking about `show()` and `hide()`  instead of `toggle()`. That works. But, I don't think I understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier with jQuery, something along these lines...

```
`<script`>
function showhide() {
$( "#showhide" ).text( "hide" );
}
`</script`>


<p>Please push this to <span id="showhide">show</span> more information about me. </p>
<button onclick="showhide()">Hi</button>
```